# string constant in angular html view instead of using controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm curious if there's a way to insert a string value instead of relying on binded constant in angular controller

for example (element created from a directive):

```
<Input-Box text="input_text" type="input_type" placeholder="input_placeholder" />
```

in the controller you have to put in:

```
$scope.input_text = "this is a value";
$scope.input_type = "text";
$scope.input_placeholder = "type something in";
```

is there a way I can override adding values to controller, and just dump it in my angular view? like we would if it was a regular html:

```
<input value="this is a value" type="text" />
```

I just don't want to keep cluttering my controller with constants.

Comment: Does enclosing it with single quote not work? `<Input-Box text="'this is a value'" />`

Comment: ugh seriously? it worked... I only tried that for "text" attribute, and the component failed, but had to add it for type and placeholder and then it work.. ugh..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the directive uses bi-directional binding, you can pass in string constant like so:

```
<Input-Box text="'this is a value'" type="'text'" placeholder="'type something in'" />
```

On another note, as per the convention for Angular directives, it is better to name your directive `input-box` rather than `Input-Box`

Comment: `Input-Box` should be `input-box` if its directive

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use it, if you don't want to use ng-model.

```
<input text="'Your value'" />
```